# alert内文章をタップ動作コピーしたい

Tags: javascript, monaca

お世話になっております。

Monacaでモバイルアプリを作成しております。

アプリ内でエラーが発生した場合、
「alert(err)」でエラー表示をしています。

この時、alert内に表示された文章をダブルタップまたはロングタップで
コピーをしたいのですが、実装方法が全くわかりません。

どなたか実装方法をご存知ならご助力お願いします。

Comment: 素のalertだとできないような気がする。。。modal作るpluginなどを利用されるのが良いかと。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/98101

Answer (score 1):

alert();が使えるなら　window.prompt ではどうでしょう
result = window.prompt( '表示するテキスト', '入力フィールドに表示されるデフォルト文字 ');
または、prompt( text, value );

Comment: できました！ありがとうございます。